# Loop and IF statement in PLSQL

Tags: plsql

I have been trying to use the IF ELSE in my PLSQL assignment

Here's the part of my current code

```
FETCH c2 into Mark, credit_hour;
    IF Mark = 'A+' THEN
        Points := Points + (4.0 * credit_hour);
    ELSIF Mark = 'A ' THEN
        Points := Points + (4.0 * credit_hour);
    ELSIF Mark = 'A-' THEN
        Points := Points + (3.7 * credit_hour);
    ELSIF Mark = 'B+' THEN
        Points := Points + (3.3 * credit_hour);
    ELSIF Mark = 'B ' THEN
        Points := Points + (3.0 * credit_hour);
    ELSIF Mark = 'B-' THEN
        Points := Points + (2.7 * credit_hour);
    ELSIF Mark = 'C+' THEN
        Points := Points + (2.3 * credit_hour);
    ELSIF Mark = 'C ' THEN
        Points := Points + (2.0 * credit_hour);
    ELSIF Mark = 'C-' THEN
        Points := Points + (1.7 * credit_hour);
    ELSIF Mark = 'D+' THEN
        Points := Points + (1.3 * credit_hour);
    ELSIF Mark = 'D ' THEN
        Points := Points + (1.0 * credit_hour);
    ELSEIF Mark = 'D-' THEN
        Points := Points + (0.7 * credit_hour);
    ELSE Mark = 'F' THEN
        Points := Points + (0.0 * credit_hour);
    END IF;
```

but then I thought that I can shorten the process by using a double parameter loop like

```
FETCH c2 into Mark, credit_hour; 
for (i,k) in (A+,A,A-,B+,B,B-,C+,C,C-,D+,D,D-,F)        (4.0,4.0,3.7,3.3,3.0,2.7,2.3,2.0,1.7,1.3,1.0,0.7,0.0)

IF Mark = i THEN 
Points := Points + (k * credit_hour);
```

but I do not know how I can do this in PLSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your current code, I would recommend to use a `case when`, since that is a lot easier to read:

```
Points := Points
          + case Mark
            when 'A+' then 4.0
            when 'A ' then 4.0
            ...
            end
            * credit_hour;
```

Or, even better, create a (temporary) table to store the values in and create a `select` statement, optionally with a join with the original table, then you don't need PL/SQL at all.

Comment: I would also propose to use a table, seems like the better approach to this problem.